# To get a table's updated time Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a column with name `points` in my Users table. Is there any simple way to get the date and time at which this column for a particular user was updated in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can check `updated_at` but it will change after any update on record.

Only good solution to that problem is to add another column, let's call it `points_updated_at` and add a callback to change it value if `points` is changed.

```
before_save do
  self.points_updated_at = Time.now if self.points_changed?
end
```

Comment: Yes, in Rails there is no default way. Need to put manual effort. :)

Comment: so how abt calling points.updated_at in my program.. will it give the correct value?

Comment: No, you will have another attribute on you object called points_updated_at.

Comment: @ArupRakshit luckily Rails is not all-in-one solution! It's not a standard feature and it's easy to implement.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Yes.. Already ORM made most of devs dumb in `SQL` :-) I mean *zero* SQL knowledge sometimes dangerous, when `#find_by_sql` comes into picture.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more column points_update_at in User table
and add call back

```
before_update {|u|
 points_update_at = Time.now if u.points_changed?
}
```